# Restrictions on Dijkstra, Bellman ford, and topoloical Shortest path algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, tree, dijkstra, shortest-path, bellman-ford

What exact restrictions/conditions are there to be able to use either of these 3 SPT algorithms on graphs in order to compute the shortest paths?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "topological shortest path"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) requires the edge lengths to be nonnegative, while [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) only requires the nonexistence of cycles of negative length.